# Mysql add group by column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to add the additional column at the end from mysql query which show the distinct records(parent_id) with increment values(column "x" in image) as attached sample in image.
Sample mysql query i tried :

```
select *, count(parent_id) as x
from businessDemands
where zip='123'
group by sub_Category_name
order by category_name desc
```

[image: Mysql query sample image]

I want same result as in image as of now its comming same with incorrect values in "x" column

Comment: `SELECT *... GROUP BY` Well, that's never going to work.

Comment: The use of `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` suggests a profound misunderstanding of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL using variables:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@p = parent_id, @rn,
                  if(@p := parent_id, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                 )
       ) as x
from t cross join
     (select @p := -1, @rn := 0) params
order by parent_id;
```

EDIT:

Variables and `GROUP BY` don't work well together.  Use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@p = parent_id, @rn,
                  if(@p := parent_id, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                 )
       ) as x
from (select . . .
      from businessDemands bd
      where zip = '123'
      order by parent_id
     ) t cross join
     (select @p := -1, @rn := 0) params
order by parent_id;
```

Fix the subquery so it is either a valid `GROUP BY` or remove the aggregation entirely.

Comment: Thanks Gordan, Now I want to add one more column name view which will show counting of group by sub_Category_name

Comment: when i add group by sub_category_name then the column "x" shows incorrect value

Comment: @Sultanjahan . . . You changed the question after I answered it.  You can make your query a *subquery* and this should work.  Variables and `group by` don't always cooperate well.

Comment: My orginal query contains same please have a look above it contains group by sub_category_name